# ¿Cómo procesar consulta JSON en FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy intentando procesar en FLUTTER/DART una consulta PHP que me llega de servidor.

```
 {"usuarios":[{"id":"12345","nombre":"pepe","apellido":"valencia","grado":"Basica"}]}
```

He intentado algunas cosas, como lo siguiente, pero no me ha funcionado,

```
var url = "https://192.168.1.12/consulta.php";
  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
    "id": id.text,
    "grado": grado.text
  });

final data = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

User user = User.fromJson(data);

String name = user['usuario'][0]['name']
String apellido = user['usuario'][0]['apellido']
String grado = user['usuario'][0]['grado']


class User {
    final List<Object> usuario;

User({
  required this.usuario
});

factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
 return User(
     usuario : parsedJson ['usuario']
  );
}
}
```

Alguna sugerencia, gracias

Comment: Que te devuelve la api? una lista de String?

Comment: Hola @Jonathan Perez , a ver si te entendí, cuando ejecuto en el browser la instrucción **https://192.168.1.12/consulta.php** me devuelve esta cadena **{"usuarios":[{"id":"12345","nombre":"pepe","apellido":"valencia","grado":"Basica"}]}**

Comment: Hola @Jonathan Perez actualice mi pregunta con lo que me sugieres, pero no me funciona. Me falta algo?

Comment: pues no, lo veo identico, no has agregado en jsonEncode en la solicitud post y la respuesta no te devuelve un Map<String, dynamic> te devuelve una lista de mapas, además si creas la clase Usuario debes agregar las variables no solo un List<Object> , así no te va a reconocer, te sugiero que primero soluciones un problema y luego otro, usa mi respuesta y trabaja con Map<String, dynamic> luego creas otra pregunta para la solución del modelo o integración, si no se hará extensa.

Answer (score 1):

Vi algunos errores, te dejo algo de como lo podrías corregir a continuación:

```
    class TestController {
  //todo ->  Data ejemplo:
  //todo ->   {
  //todo ->     "usuarios": [
  //todo ->       "id": "123",
  //todo ->       "nombre": "Pepe",
  //todo ->       "apellido": "Valencia",
  //todo ->       "grado": "Basica",
  //todo ->     ]
  //todo ->   }

  //todo -> Primero notamos que hay dato clave: valor
  //todo -> donde la clave viene siendo "usuarios" y el valor la lista de usuarios como tal

  Future<void> getUsers() async {
    String apiConsulta = "tu api";

    //todo -> En el body está el primer error, primero debes codificar el cuerpo de la solicitud
    //todo -> para que la api pueda entender que estás enviando
    final request = await http.post(Uri.parse(apiConsulta),
        body: jsonEncode({"id": id.text, "grado": grado.text}));

    //todo -> Aquí hacemos una pequeña validación para ver si la solicitud se generó correctamente o no
    if (request.statusCode == 200) {
      //todo -> Al ser un mapa no solo te regresa una Lista de String, te regresa un mapa, aquí esta el segundo error:
      //List<String> usuarios = [];
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> usuarios = [];

      //todo -> para que no estés seteando la data uno por uno sería mejor que lo hagas con un ciclo for:
      final users = jsonDecode(request.body);

         //todo -> me olvidaba de ingresar a los valores de usuario
  final allUsers = users["usuarios"];

  if (allUsers.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {
      usuarios.add(allUsers[i]);
    }
  } else {
    print("No se encontraron datos almacenados con este id y grado");
    return;
  }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Jonathan Perez gracias por tu respuesta, he estado probando tu sugerencia, pero no logro que me funcione. He notado que hasta la instrucción **final users = jsonDecode(request.body);** funciona bien, en la variable **users** llega la cadena, pero a partir de la instrucción **if (users.length > 0)** el código no se ejecuta y no he podido extraer los valores de la cadena.

Comment: si, tienes razón, me olvidé de un dato en específico, ya actualizo la respuesta